# WCF-The request channel timed out after 1 min, while sendTimeout="00:25:00" on both sides

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I am getting the error of "The request channel timed out after 1 min" even sendTimeout="00:25:00" on both sides.
If request is less than 1 min in time, then there is no issue but issue arises on request taking processing of greater than 1 min. on WCF service.

On WCF service side I have following bindings in my web.config file

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00" >
      <security mode="None" ></security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>  
</bindings>
```

On Client side, I have following bindings in my app.config file

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="streambinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" closeTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00" transferMode="Streamed">
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

from your config file of service and client I could make out that, your service bindingconfiguration is default I mean it doesn't have any name given, but client side binding configuration has a binding name. Try to keep it same both at the service and client, either have a name for binding configuration in service or remove the name from the client. Since you are accessing with different bindingName WCF not able to recognize the exact configuration and it might be timing out.

Comment: Yes, I also did this.. but the main thing was that I did not add     [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)] tag in my service class.